# Gradients do not exist for variables ['pred/kernel:0', 'pred/bias:0'] when minimizing the loss

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, loss-function

I have tried to implement my own accuracy loss function to use with tensorflow_ranking, but my gradient's are not being propagated it seems. Everything works fine when using a different loss, so I believe all of my layers are connected and the problem lies in my loss function.

```
def PrecisionLoss(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight, ragged=True):
    if ragged:
        y_pred = y_pred.to_tensor()
        y_true = y_true.to_tensor()
    batch_size = tf.shape(y_true)[0]
    list_size = tf.shape(y_pred)[1]
    ranked_y_pred = tf.add(
        tf.math.top_k(
            -tf.math.top_k(-y_pred, k=list_size)[1],
            k=list_size)[1],
        1)
    ranked_y_true = tf.add(
        tf.math.top_k(
            -tf.math.top_k(-y_true, k=list_size)[1],
            k=list_size)[1],
        1)
    comparisons = tf.cast(
        tf.math.equal(ranked_y_pred, ranked_y_true),
        tf.int32)
    comparisons = tf.math.subtract(
        tf.ones((batch_size,list_size), dtype=tf.int32),
        comparisons 
    )
    powers = tf.math.subtract(
        tf.fill((batch_size,list_size), list_size),
        ranked_y_true)
    base = tf.fill((batch_size, list_size), 2)
    lambda_weights = tf.math.subtract(
        tf.pow(base, powers),
        tf.ones((batch_size, list_size), dtype=tf.int32))
    comparisons = tf.cast(
        tf.math.multiply(comparisons, lambda_weights),
        tf.float32)

    return tf.reduce_sum(
                tf.squeeze(
                    tf.reduce_sum(comparisons, axis=1, keepdims=True)),
                axis=0)
```

A brief description of the loss function: It takes ragged predictions and ragged labels and ranks the labels and predictions by their score/value. If the prediction equals its label its loss is 0, otherwise it is 1. This loss tensor of 1s and 0s is then multiplied by a weight tensor:

```
base^(list_size - rank) - 1
```

So that the non-zero losses place greater weight on ranks near 1, and little to no weight on ranks near list_size.

As far as I see I only use tf functions everywhere, so I would think the loss should propagate.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

EDIT: This is my entire model if you want to look at it:

```
class ScoringModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, activation, feat1_dims, other_dims, max_list_size):
        super().__init__()

        self.activation = activation
        self.split_index = max_list_size*feat1_dims+ other_dims
        self.max_list_size= max_list_size
        self.embeddings_dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)
        # self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name='dropout')

        self.embeddings_dense_32 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(0.03), activation='relu', name='embeddings_dense_32')
        self.embeddings_dense_16 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(0.03), activation='relu', name='embeddings_dense_16')

        # self.dense_64 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name='dense_4')
        # self.dense_32 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu", name='dense_5')
        self.dense_16 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(0.03), activation="relu", name='dense_6')
        self.dense_16_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu", name='dense_7')
        self.dense_16_3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu", name='dense_8')
        self.pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.max_list_size, activation=self.activation, name='pred')
    
    def __call__(self, inputs):

        embeds = inputs[:, :self.split_index]
        continuous = inputs[:, self.split_index:]

        z = self.embeddings_dense_32(embeds)
        # z = self.embeddings_dropout(z, training=True)
        z = self.embeddings_dense_16(z)
        # z = self.embeddings_dropout(z, training=True)

        x = tf.concat([z, continuous], axis=1)
        
        # # x = self.dropout(x, training=True)
        # x = self.dense_64(x)

        # x = self.dense_16(inputs)
        # x = self.dense_32(x)
        # x = self.dropout(x, training=True)
        x = self.dense_16(x)
        # x = self.dropout(x, training=True)
        # x = self.dense_16_2(x)
        # # # # x = self.dropout(x, training=True)
        # x = self.dense_16_3(x)
        # x = self.dropout(x, training=True)
        x = self.pred(x)
        return x

class RankingModel(tf.keras.Model):
    
    def __init__(self, embeddings, continuous, vocab_size_dict, dim_dict, loss, max_list_size, activation='sigmoid'):
        super().__init__()
        self.embeddings = embeddings
        self.continuous = continuous
        self.embedding_layers = {}
        self.vocab_size_dict = vocab_size_dict
        self.dim_dict = dim_dict
        self.loss = loss
        self.max_list_size= max_list_size
        self.activation = activation
        self.other_dims = 0
        for key,value in dim_dict.items():
            if key != 'feat1':
                self.other_dims += value

        self.embedding_layers['feat1'] = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
            self.vocab_size_dict['feat1']+1,
            self.dim_dict['feat1'],
            name='feat1')

        self.embedding_layers['feat2'] = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
            self.vocab_size_dict['feat2']+1,
            self.dim_dict['feat2'],
            name='feat2')

        self.embedding_layers['feat3'] = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
            self.vocab_size_dict['feat3']+1,
            self.dim_dict['feat3'],
            name='feat3')

        self.embedding_layers['feat4'] = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
            self.vocab_size_dict['feat4']+1,
            self.dim_dict['feat4'],
            name='feat4')

        self.embedding_layers['feat5'] = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
            self.vocab_size_dict['feat5']+1,
            self.dim_dict['feat5'],
            name='feat5')

        self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()

        self.score_model =  ScoringModel(self.activation, self.dim_dict['feat1'], self.other_dims, self.max_list_size)
        
        self.task = tfrs.tasks.Ranking(
            loss=self.loss,
            metrics=[
                tfr.keras.metrics.PrecisionMetric(name="1st_Precision", topn = 1, ragged=True),
                tfr.keras.metrics.PrecisionMetric(name="2nd_Precision", topn = 2, ragged=True),
                tfr.keras.metrics.PrecisionMetric(name="3rd_Precision", topn = 3, ragged=True),
                tfr.keras.metrics.OPAMetric(name="Head to Head Accuracy", ragged=True)
            ]
        )

    def __call__(self, features, training=True):
        feats = []
        for feat, tens in features.items():
            if feat in self.embeddings:
                if feat != 'feat1':
                    embedding = self.embedding_layers[feat](tens[:,3])
                    # flatten = self.flatten(embedding)
                    feats.append(embedding)
                else:
                    embedding = self.embedding_layers[feat](tens)
                    flatten = self.flatten(embedding)
                    feats.append(flatten)
            if feat == 'continuous':
                if self.continuous:
                    flatten = self.flatten(tens[:, :, 10])
                    feats.append(flatten)
        
        deep_concatenated = tf.concat(feats, axis=1)

        scores = self.score_model(deep_concatenated)

        masked_scores = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(scores, features['mask'])

        return masked_scores
    
    def compute_loss(self, features, training=False):
        labels = features['label']
        masked_labels = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(labels, features['mask'])

        scores = self(features)
        return self.task(masked_labels, scores)

    def train_step(self, inputs):
        """Custom train step using the `compute_loss` method."""

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            loss = self.compute_loss(inputs, training=True)

            # Handle regularization losses as well.
            regularization_loss = sum(self.losses)

            total_loss = loss + regularization_loss

        gradients = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_variables)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.trainable_variables))

        metrics = {metric.name: metric.result() for metric in self.metrics}
        # metrics["loss"] = loss
        # # metrics["regularization_loss"] = regularization_loss
        metrics["total_loss"] = total_loss

        return metrics

    def test_step(self, inputs):
        """Custom test step using the `compute_loss` method."""

        loss = self.compute_loss(inputs, training=True)

        # Handle regularization losses as well.
        regularization_loss = sum(self.losses)

        total_loss = loss + regularization_loss

        metrics = {metric.name: metric.result() for metric in self.metrics}
        # metrics["loss"] = loss
        # # metrics["regularization_loss"] = regularization_loss
        metrics["total_loss"] = total_loss

        return metrics
```

Comment: This loss is not differentiable, you cannot use it to train with gradient descent.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Wow, duh. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Do you think this can be made differentiable? I assume it is the tf.math.top_k function that ruins it all.

Comment: No, it is tf.cast and tf.math.equal, both are not differentiable.